# collective intelligence by toby sergaram chapter 4 crawler is not working

Tags: python, search, ranking

I am using this book and tried to download links by using crawler. But i dont know why anything is not happening. I followed page 55,57 code but no links are coming as per him.

here is the code:

File name linkextractCrawler.py

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import *
from urlparse import urljoin
# Create a list of words to ignore

class crawler:

  # Initialize the crawler with the name of database
  def __init__(self,dbname):
    pass
  def __del__(self):
    pass
  def dbcommit(self):
    pass
  # Auxilliary function for getting an entry id and adding
  # it if it's not present
  def getentryid(self,table,field,value,createnew=True):
    return None
  # Index an individual page
  def addtoindex(self,url,soup):
    print 'Indexing %s' % url
  # Extract the text from an HTML page (no tags)
  def gettextonly(self,soup):
    return None
  # Separate the words by any non-whitespace character
  def separatewords(self,text):
    return None
# Return true if this url is already indexed
  def isindexed(self,url):
    return False
  # Add a link between two pages
  def addlinkref(self,urlFrom,urlTo,linkText):
    pass
  # Starting with a list of pages, do a breadth
  # first search to the given depth, indexing pages
  # as we go
  def crawl(self,pages,depth=2):
    pass
  # Create the database tables
  def createindextables(self):
    pass

ignorewords=set(['the','of','to','and','a','in','is','it'])

print("kk");

def crawl(self,pages,depth=2):
    for i in range(depth):
      newpages=set( )
      for page in pages:
        try:
          c=urllib2.urlopen(page)
        except:
          print "Could not open %s" % page
          continue
        soup=BeautifulSoup(c.read( ))
        self.addtoindex(page,soup)
        links=soup('a')
        for link in links:
          if ('href' in dict(link.attrs)):
            url=urljoin(page,link['href'])
            if url.find("'")!=-1: continue
            url=url.split('#')[0]  # remove location portion
            if url[0:4]=='http' and not self.isindexed(url):
              newpages.add(url)
            linkText=self.gettextonly(link)
            self.addlinkref(page,url,linkText)
        self.dbcommit( )
    pages=newpages
    print("kk");
    print(pages);
```

On console:

```
>>> import linkextractCrawler
>>> p = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl.html']
>>> crawler=linkextractCrawler.crawler('')
>>> crawler.crawl(p)
>>>
```

Comment: You have two functions named `crawl` in your code, and the one you're calling is the one that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Well i am following him and atleast it should work, can u help me ? I am doing my project and studying it

Comment: here is the book link http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1436211857